# What is the difference between havingCondition and having?

Tags: database

Drupal dynamic queries have 2 conditional clauses called having and havingCondition.

The [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/310086) states "The Having clause behaves identically to the WHERE clause, except that it uses methods havingCondition() and having() instead of condition() and where()."

Other than this I can't find any mention of either clauses anywhere (including in the examples module), or any examples of their use.

What is the difference between the 2 functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out though trail and error.

Example of a having clause:

```
$query->having('user_count > 0');
```

Example of a havingCondition clause:

```
$query->havingCondition('user_count', 0, '>');
```

Essentially you can pass the alias, value and operator as separate arguments into havingCondition, but have to pass them all as one string into having.